# EF Core One-to-One relationship with Shadow properties as a Keys using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I can't resolve the One-to-One relationship between two classes using Shadow Properties as a Keys. Unfortunately I can't create real key properties into my classes due to I used 3rd party class library.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;

namespace EFCoreTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create database");
            using (var context = new ClassDbContext())
            {
                if (!context.Database.EnsureDeleted())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" => Can't delete database");
                }
                if (context.Database.EnsureCreated())
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine(" => Done");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" => Can't create database");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }
    }
    public class ClassDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<ClassA> ClassA { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ClassB> ClassB { get; set; }
        public ClassDbContext()
        {
        }
        public ClassDbContext(DbContextOptions<ClassDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;Database=XXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX");
            }
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>().Property<int>("ClassAId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().Property<int>("ClassBId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().Property<int>("AnotherClassId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().HasOne(p => p.AnotherClass).WithMany().HasForeignKey("AnotherClassId");
        }
    }
    public class ClassA
    {
        public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    }
    public class ClassB
    {
        public string PropertyB { get; set; }
        public ClassA AnotherClass { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EF Core returns with the following error, which is very confused me:

> **System.InvalidOperationException**: 'The relationship from 'ClassB.AnotherClass' to 'ClassA' with foreign key properties
>   {'AnotherClassId' : **int**} cannot target the primary key {'ClassAId'
>   : **int**} *because it is not compatible*. Configure a principal key
>   or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.'

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the automatic binding of properties to keys, implemented in EF Core through the naming of properties, **does not work in this case**!

**They require you to force a key name before creating a connection!**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>().Property<int>("ClassAId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>().HasKey("ClassAId"); // <=== This is a SOLUTION
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().Property<int>("ClassBId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().Property<int>("AnotherClassId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().HasOne(p => p.AnotherClass).WithMany().HasForeignKey("AnotherClassId");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this works with EF Core 1.0.1, but  2.2.1 returns an error.